# When to use OR and when to use UNION in sql while using nested Select quires

Tags: sql

I was trying to use nested Select query
Using OR:

```
select * from TRANSACTION_LOG
where GLOBAL_ID IN (select UNIQUE GLOBAL_ID from ORDER_REF where ORDER_ID in ('O01625','O01628','O01640'))
OR (GLOBAL_ID ='MC11f5f14');
```

The other way was using UNION ALL:

```
select * from TRANSACTION
where GLOBAL_ID IN (select UNIQUE GLOBAL_ID from ORDER_REF where ORDER_ID in ('O01625','O01628','O01640'))
UNION ALL
select * from TRANSACTION
where GLOBAL_ID ='MC11f5f14';
```

The first query is taking too much time for result, while the second one was quick, Not sure why and how it works!

Comment: How can I answer your question better?

Comment: **UNION ALL** usually is faster because will get duplicates as result

Answer (score 1):

First, the standard SQL construct is `select distinct`, not `select unique`.  Second, neither is needed with `in`.

So, the first query should be written as:

```
select tl.*
from TRANSACTION_LOG tl
where tl.GLOBAL_ID in (select o.GLOBAL_ID
                       from ORDER_REF o
                       where o.ORDER_ID in ('O01625', 'O01628', 'O01640')
                      ) or
      tl.GLOBAL_ID = 'MC11f5f14';
```

The equivalent query with `union all` is:

```
select tl.*
from TRANSACTION_LOG tl
where tl.GLOBAL_ID = 'MC11f5f14'
union all
select tl.*
from TRANSACTION_LOG tl
where tl.GLOBAL_ID in (select o.GLOBAL_ID
                       from ORDER_REF o
                       where o.ORDER_ID in ('O01625', 'O01628', 'O01640')
                      ) and
      tl.GLOBAL_ID <> 'MC11f5f14';
 -----^
```

Note the additional clause.  This allows the query to use `union all` rather than `union`.  `union` incurs a performance penalty because it removes duplicates.

Which is better?  That can depend on the database.  Some databases have sophisticated optimizers.  Some don't.  Some databases prefer `exists` to `in` for optimization.

In general, the second form allows more choices for optimization.  However, if you don't have appropriate indexes on the tables, then all bets are off.

Comment: the first option is taking forever to fetch the results, still not clear why so?

Comment: @PrashathKesari . . . The first is not the option I'm proposing.  It is just rewritten for standard SQL.  The second is the improved version.